# Opengl, render an object pose

Tags: opengl, matrix, rotation

I want to rotate a 3d object in a roll pitch yaw fashion.
I store the pose of the object in a matrix, and perform roll, pitch and yaw rotations multiplying the pose matrix by one of the standard rotation matrices about x, y, or z axis.

Then I display it using these lines of code.

```
void display()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluLookAt(-5, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  glPushMatrix();
    ship.Draw();
  glPopMatrix();
  glutSwapBuffers(); 
}
void Spacecraft::Draw(){
  glMultMatrixf(pose);
  model.Draw();
  return;
}
```

It works, but the object, instead to rotate around their own axis it rotates around the world axis... 
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rotations are always about the origin of the local coordinate system. So you first have to translate the coordinate system so that the center of the desired rotation happens to be at the local coordinate system origin. It's hard to tell where and which transformations to apply without seeing the rest of your code.

The rest of the drawing code, which is not shown, also includes the contents of the model. Draw function. Most likely you've got a translations somewhere in there. This translation moves the object away from the coordinate system center. I think what you're missing (not about OpenGL but linear algebra in general) is, that matrix multiplication is non-commutative, i.e. order of operations matter and that for column major matrices the order of operations is last to first (or right to left if written in normal notation). So the rotation must be the *last* thing you multiply on the matrix, not the first.

Comment: Thanks, I know that, the point is that the object rotates, but instead to rotate around its own axes it rotate around world axes! But when I checked that when for example I rotate it about the z axis, the third column vector of its pose matrix does not change, but when I display it object does not rotate around it...
I think I missing something about openGL...

Comment: @giuseppe: Then your model's mesh is not properly centered at the origin. This can happen easily for example models created with Blender. Each mesh object has an object center, relative to which the mesh is laid out. Now if the mesh is located away from the object center, if you don't know about this peculiarity you might move the whole object to apparently bring it back into the right location. Solution: Properly center the mesh in the exported model. In addition to that it's advisable to also export the models local transformation matrix and multiply before drawing the mesh.